# Get coordinates realative to stage from rectangle in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Allright first time asker here so be gentle

I got a pane with a borderpane on with some vboxes and hboxes in those are rectangles that represents a monopoly board.

Now to move the circles that represents the players I need the relative coordinates of the rectangles corner to the stage and not those relative to the vbox or hbox how do I go about doing this getLayoutX()/Y and getX()/Y are not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given `child` is a node for which you desire to determine scene level co-ordinates:

```
Bounds boundsInScene = child.localToScene(child.getBoundsInLocal());
```